# Error related swapping ERC20 Token on UNISWAP

Tags: metamask, uniswap

I am trying to swap simple ERC20 Token on UNISWAP, I have added liquidity successfully.
But, when I try to swap it fails after approving both tokens and give the error "Too little received"
I am unable to understand what this error means.
Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: What are the contract? Usually the error means there is not enough liquidity in the pool and the price will change too much. It is possible to bypass the warning by setting a large slippage, but the warning means you will be losing money.

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x58c58c199548ff95ece0c48aad3b3b27ff6c3fa1#writeContract

This is the contract. And I have added enough liquidity in it.. Also, I've tried by increasing slippage.

Comment: That's the token address, the [pool address](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xe4cc3a0932d6d1355a25cbbcc7fd68f1e0e03390#code) doesn't have enough liquidity.

Comment: This is our [pool address](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x76d4217941BADd5E2447681aF15A4bF244F5c2bf#readContract)

we have added liquidity for [TestToken](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xD13Bab32432c7A3795d9Bfc34719dA58669b6c3a) and [BabyUSDT](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x58c58c199548ff95ece0c48aad3b3b27ff6c3fa1#code)